# will I get android updates on Moto G after Cyanogenmod 11

Tags: cyanogenmod, ota-update, android-versions, motorola-moto-g

I'm about to flash Cynogenmod 11 on my Moto G XT1033. I was wondering that, will I still get android OTA updates even after installing CM11?
If anyone have an answer then please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CyanogenMod has its own OTA Updater. You will not get the official Android updates, but the CM updates.

Comment: Will i get the OTA update quicker than the official update?

Comment: @Sarthak Most likely, yes... especially if you use nightlies, instead of the stable version. But take note that Android source code usually comes out first. Then, the CM guys just look at that and see which ones they'll add to CM.